# Error Message: (It looks like your post is mostly code...) appear for me while it's not?

Tags: support, asking-questions, quality-filter

I was going to ask a question to solve a problem in my code. I described it and inserted the code which has the problem, but I get an error message:

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details

It appeared for me, and I could not post my question. I took a screenshot of my post:

[image]

What is my mistake?

Comment: Your post *is* mostly code, though. I'd wager 90% of that code could be removed from the question, once you've identified which specific part is causing the issue. The warning is specifically designed to prevent people from dumping their entire application and asking someone to debug it for them.

Answer (score 21):

Questions like this, where you dump a load of code and ask if there's a problem with it, are poor-quality questions for the following reasons:

- The fact that your program is not doing what you wanted it to means, by definition, there is obviously an error in your code.
- We do not know what you expect your code to be doing, why you expect it to be doing it, or what it's actually doing.
- Most of the code you're posting likely has nothing to do with the problem you are facing, which makes it hard for us (and future readers) to identify the problem.
- Questions like this are usually symptomatic of someone who has not attempted any debugging of their own.

Ultimately, Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a debugging service.  It's important that the questioner has done their research and at least made an effort to solve the problem themself.  Questions like this show no evidence of this, and we would rather point that out to the asker before the question goes live so that they can fix it.

Answer (score 8):

That's a good thing to raise an error if the question has a bad ratio of description/code. A readable question should be very easy to understand without having to learn the culture of the project by reading the code first.

In fact, the code to reproduce an issue shouldn't be your actual code that results with the issue, but rather a derivated snippet of that code which also reproduces the issue. That way, when someone gets by with an explanation, the description part of your question will be enough for him or her to get the idea of what you are doing. Once the issue is resolved in that snippet you can migrate the change to your actual code.

What usually happens with "mostly code" questions is that, while the code is already huge, it still doesn't go over dependencies or related code that doesn't seem to be related, so the provided code is incomplete. I often see this: `I still have this issue: (talks about a completely new error caused by a side effect)`. The provided answers are now required to investigate new issues that weren't in the initial question. Having a short snippet to reproduce the issue prevents this.

My rule of thumb for judging if a question seems well written and looks good to answer is an arbitrary 50/50. Always put some code in your question, but keep it short and introduce it with a decent amount of description about what it is - rather than what it does around your business logic. Others need to have a decent idea of what's going on even before reading the code. You might improve your question by finding the location of your issue, then cut it down and refactor it so it isn't part of your project culture anymore.